# How to group today's records by Hour created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, morris.js

I'm using Rails 4.2, SQLite, and Morris.js to create graphs and statistics about the sales movement. I'm trying to create a line graph that shows the sum of the totals of orders grouped by hour. Like between 9am and 10 am we sold a number of orders of sum of X dollars

app/views/static_pages/stats.html.erb

```
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <h4>Today:</h4>
    <%= content_tag :div, "", id: "orders_tdh_chart", data: { orders: orders_tdh_chart } %>
  </div>
```

staic_pages_helper.rb

```
  def orders_tdh_chart
    Order.where("created_at >= ?", Date.today.beginning_of_day).group("strftime('%H', created_at)").sum(:total_after_discount)
  end
```

static_pages.coffee

```
  Morris.line
    element: 'orders_tdh_chart'
    data: $('#orders_tdh_chart').data('orders')
    xkey: 'created_at'
    ykeys: [ 'total_after_discount' ]
    labels: [ 'Total' ]
```

The graph returns empty and also all the other graphs in the view returns empty after it was working. also in the console the generated query returns very strange as the following...

```
   ...
   (0.3ms)  SELECT SUM("orders"."total_after_discount") AS sum_total_after_discount, strftime('%H', created_at) AS strftime_h_created_at FROM "orders" WHERE (created_at >= '2016-10-14 00:00:00.000000') GROUP BY strftime('%H', created_at)
   (0.2ms)  SELECT SUM("orders"."total_after_discount") FROM "orders" WHERE (date(created_at) = '2016-09-17')
   (0.2ms)  SELECT SUM("orders"."total_after_discount") FROM "orders" WHERE (date(created_at) = '2016-09-18')
   (0.2ms)  SELECT SUM("orders"."total_after_discount") FROM "orders" WHERE (date(created_at) = '2016-09-19')
   ...
```

Comment: By "at 10 am" what do you really mean?  Isn't it "between 9am and 10 am"?

Comment: yes of course, my bad